# Compiling single vs multiple source files in Intel Fortran

Tags: performance, fortran, intel-fortran

I have been compiling a project with modules and subroutines in different files. Each subroutine written in separate file. The same for the modules. Then, I tested compiling these files separately to object files (-c) and than linking with the optimization flags, and also using cat to merge the entire source code and applying the same procedure to this single source file. What I found is that the executable generated by compiling the single file was about 40% faster than that generated by the multiple files, despite using exactly same flags for both. 
I would like to know if anyone knows why it is happening, and if there is any flag on the Intel Fortran compiler that compiles multiple files as they were a single file.

Comment: I think we need the code for that. My first suspicion is that the subroutine you're testing is very simple, and instead of creating a new stack frame, the compiler just does the subroutine's job in the active stack frame. But when it doesn't know what the subroutine does, it can't do that. But again, we'd need the code for that.

Comment: Well, I cannot hand the code at this time. I can say that the code was the 3D solution of a convection-dispersion problem using finite difference with an operator overloading automatic differentiation code for the derivatives. Therefore, I do not believe the code would be that simple.

Comment: What compilation options do you use?  In particular, the `-ipo` family?

Comment: You get IPO automatically within a single file but not multiple files. Try enabling IPO explicitly so that it's active across files.

Comment: I used "-openmp -fpp2 -O3 -o", I have also used "-fast", which provided the lowest CPU time for both cases.

Comment: I can't reproduce what you are saying. If you can't show the real code, maybe you can make some mockup that compiles and exhibits this behaviour?

Comment: You should try `-ipo1` instead of `-ipo` because the former flag forces the creation of a single object file, while the latter might still split a larger codebase to several object files. BTW, for `gfortran` you would use `-flto -flto-partition=none`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As @chw21 requested, I created a small program showing the problem:

```
program main
    use operators
    implicit none

    integer :: n
    real(8), dimension(:,:), allocatable :: a, b, c
    integer :: i,j,k

    n = 1000

    allocate(a(n,n), b(n,n), c(n,n))

    call random_number(a)
    call random_number(b)

    do j = 1, n
        do i = 1, n
            do k = 1, n
                !c(i,j) = c(i,j) + a(k,i) * b(k,j)
                c(i,j) = add(c(i,j), mul(a(k,i), b(k,j)))
            enddo
        enddo
    enddo

    write(*,*) sum(c)

end program
```

with module:

```
module operators

contains

    function add(a,b) result (c)
        real(8), intent(in) :: a, b
        real(8) :: c

        c = a + b
    end function

    function mul(a,b) result (c)
        real(8), intent(in) :: a, b
        real(8) :: c

        c = a * b
    end function
end module
```

The idea is that these functions should normally get inlined, if the compiler knows that they are so extremely small. I did three tests with `-O2`:

1. complete source in a single file
2. split in two files
3. split in two files with `-ipo` (or `-flto`)

The results for `ifort 13.0.0` and `gfortran 5.2.0` on different machines are:

```
Test     |   1.  |   2.  |   3.  
---------+-------+-------+-------
ifort    |  1.3s | 15.7s |  1.9s
gfortran |  1.1s |  3.7s |  1.1s
```

Unfortunately, I don't know why there is still a difference between the 1st and 3rd test with ifort ... I guess, a look at the generated code would shed some light on this issue.

**Update:** The times were measured by executing `time ./a.out` which resulted in stable times. Due to the standard compilation with `ifort -O2`, the maximum instruction set should be SSE2 (thus, no FMA), the processor supports upto SSE4a (Opteron 6128). An additional test on a recent Intel processor (upto AVX) showed similar results.

An important thing seems to be the lack of inlining and vectorization of the inner loop, which gets applied during IPO and single-file-compilation (see `--opt-report`). Additionally, there seem to be some differences concerning vectorization between IPO and single-file-compilation.

Comment: How did you perform testing? I'm little bit concerned about ifort results for case #2...

Comment: I have used his code, and I can more or less confirm the strange behaviour of the intel fortran compiler: If module and program are in the same file, it runs in only 0.3s, if they are in separate files, it takes 5.2s

Comment: I have tested both intel compiler 12.1.9.293 and 15.0.3.187, and both exhibit such a strange behaviour.

Comment: With `gfortran`, both cases come in at 4.4s

Comment: Since `ifort` is so much better when either in a single source file, or with `-ipo`, I assume that the compiler can do some serious optimisation.

Comment: What kind of CPU do you have? Does it have the FMA instructions? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FMA_instruction_set Does the final code use them?

Comment: What did you get when you compile using a single file and the -ipo?

Comment: @BrunoF There are some small differences in the output of `--opt-report` but the execution time doesn't change.